# .XLS File format is not valid for react-export-excel third party library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have worked on react-export-excel third party library for creating an excel file but it works .xlsx file only. It doesn't work .xls file format. I have changed the file format Xls file. After I opened the .xls File format is not valid that error occurred.

```
<ExcelFile element={
    <MDBIcon icon="file-excel" size="2x" className="green-text" />} filename="Email" fileExtension="xls">
        <ExcelSheet data={props.email} name="Employees">
            <ExcelColumn label="Email" value="Email" />
            <ExcelColumn label="Quota" value="Quota" />
        </ExcelSheet>
</ExcelFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're using an outdated fork (https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel)

Use `npm install react-data-export --save`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export because they [support](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/f42ec5ef3f70bddf6b7882d8aa61565d021fe904/src/ExcelPlugin/components/ExcelFile.js#L82) `bookType` from [`xlsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#supported-output-formats) npm package used under the hood in both libs.

Comment: I tried both libraries but .xls file did not work. When I open the .xls file, an error occurred such as File format is not valid. What is the issue??

But both library's default file format is .xlsx. it works for me. Although I want to create .xls file only.

Comment: I think that's because you have `<MDBIcon>` inside of your `<ExcelFile>`. Try moving it outside.

Comment: Najathi, Did you resolve the above issue? I am also facing similar issue and .xls format is not opening. If you have found the solution already, could you share it to me?

Comment: I have the same problem with .xls format, how to fix this problem?